# Regex doesn't seem to work properly in my code

Tags: javascript, regex

What I am trying to do is turn, for example "{{John}}" into "John".

First I am parsing from a string:

```
var parametrar = content.match(/[{{]+[Aa-Åå]+[}}]/g);
```

Here regex works fine and it parses as it should. I need to parse the "{}" to find stuff in the string.

But then I'm trying to parse out the "{}" from each "parametrar":

```
for (var i = 0; i < parametrar.length; i++) {
    parametrar = parametrar[i].replace(/[{}]/g, "");
}
```

When I alert "parametrar" all I get is one "a". I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here, seems it should work.

Comment: Why do you put `{{` in square brackets (`[{{]`)? Why not simply `\{\{` (or even  just `{{`, though I usually escape all parentheses/braces/brackets to be on the safe side)? Same goes for `}}`.

Comment: And: `[Aa-Åå]` looks wrong. First, it should probably be `[A-Åa-å]` (or even better use a character class if possible, e.g. `\w` for a word character), second if you want case-insensitive matching, there should be a regex flag for that which goes after the closing `/`.

Comment: Are you sure the regex is fine? `[Aa-Åå]` matches `A`, `å` and any character between `a` and `Å` (see the [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) table for details).

Comment: Why capture anything? Just remove all `{{` and `{{` that are before/after a letter: `[{](?=[a-zA-ZÅå])` (replace with empty string) and `([a-zA-ZÅå])\}` (replace with `$1`).

Comment: @stakx 

`parametrar = parametrar[i].replace("\{\{", "");                    
parametrar = parametrar[i].replace("\}\}", "");`

Returns only the letter "j".

Comment: @stribizhev Can you please elaborate what you mean. What does the "$1" do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match the name with braces around and then just use the first capturing group (`m[1]`):

```js
var re = /\{{2}([a-zA-ZÅå]+)\}{2}/g; 
var str = '{{John}}';
 
if ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
  paramterar = m[1];
  alert(paramterar);
}
```

If you have a larger string that contains multiple `{{NAME}}`s, you can use the code I suggested in my comment:

```js
var re = /\{{2}([a-zA-ZÅå]+)\}{2}/g; 
var str = 'My name is {{John}} and {{Vasya}}.';
var arr = [];

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
  paramterar = m[1];
  arr.push(m[1]);
}

alert(arr);
alert(str.replace(/([a-zA-ZÅå])\}{2}/g,"$1").replace(/\{{2}(?=[a-zA-ZÅå])/g, ""))
```

I have also fixed the character class to only accept English letters + `Å` and `å` (revert if it is not the case, but note that `[Aa-Åå]` is not matching any upper case Englihs letters from B to Z, and matches characters like `§`.) Please check the [ANSI table](http://www.alanwood.net/demos/ansi.html) to see what range you need.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add greedy matching to maque's answer with using question mark(?).

`"{{John}}".replace(/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/g,"$1");`

It extracts "John" properly from "{{John}} and Martin}}" input. Otherwise it matches to "John}} and Martin".

Answer (score 0):

Just do it like that:

```
"{{John}}".replace(/\{\{(.*)\}\}/g,"$1");
```

So you are searching for string that have double '{' (these needs to be escaped), then there is something (.*) then again '}' and your output is first match of the block.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var parametrar = content.replace(/\{\{([a-åA-Å]+)\}\}/g, "$1");
```

This gives you a "purified" string. If you want an array, than you can do this:

```
var parametrar = content.match(/\{\{[a-åA-Å]+\}\}/g);
for (var i = 0, len = parametrar.length; i < len; i++) {
    parametrar = parametrar[i].replace(/\{\{([a-åA-Å]+)\}\}/g, "$1");
}
```

Comment: This should work but it doesn't. I get the full "{{John}}" string in the alertbox.